# applying quantiles on an array in R

Tags: r, arrays, quantile

Say I have an array comb_res of dim (100,150,100). And I calculate another array of products of (i,j)_th elements.

```
comb_res<-array(rnorm(1500000,0,1),c(100,150,100))
combi.prod<-array(0,c(100,150,100))
  for (i in 1:dim(comb_res)[1]) {
    for (j in 1:dim(comb_res)[3]) {
     # i=5;j=2
     combi.prod[i,,j]<- comb_res[i,,j]*comb_res[j,,i]
    }
  }
```

I want to apply quantile function (say c(0.5,0.9)) on the 150 matrices to get the quantile matrices. How to do that?

Comment: Please construct a small example for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you mean, I think that the following should work:

```r
sapply(1:150, function(x) quantile(combi.prod[,x,], probs = c(.5, .9)))
```

You could, of course, change with the length of the second dimension of the array for an array of a different size.